# Why am I getting an error when uploading a small CSV file to BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

The error message is

> Failed to create table: Error while reading data, error message: Error detected while parsing row starting at position: 0. Error: Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered.

Comment: Please don’t link to things. Add all information directly to your question preferably as editable text

Comment: Alright. Got it.

Comment: Your file contains bad characters - you need to fix your file

Comment: Hi Nick. It' resolved. I just forgot to save it as a CSV file. Thanks!